# Define C# preprocessor from MsBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild

In my `C#` file I want to have a preprocessor condition like this:

```
#if DEMO
    ShowSplash();
#endif
```

I'm running this command from command line:

```
MSBuild MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:DEMO=1
```

Then, in `MyProject.csproj` file I have the following:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEMO=$(DEMO)</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But the preprocessor seems to skip my splash code. (I'm aware of the difference between "Any CPU" and "AnyCPU". I never touched that, so I'm quite sure Visual Studio doesn't care about the space.)

`DEMO` is not defined? The same construct seems to work in other project types (e.g. `.wixproj`) **What am I missing here?**

Comment: Did you try clean/rebuild the project after editing `.csproj`?

Comment: No, but I do see this now: `warning MSB3052: The parameter to the compiler is invalid, '/define:DEMO=1'`

Comment: `<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants> <DefineConstants Condition=" $(DEMO) == 1 ">$(DefineConstants);DEMO</DefineConstants>`

Comment: You could perhaps use the command line somewhat differently, like `MSBuild MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:Conditionals=DEMO`. In your project you would then use `<DefineConstants>TRACE;$(Conditionals)</DefineConstants>`. (might or might not work; i have not tested it...)

Comment: @PetSerAl, that works. It seems that CSC does not support `#if X=1`. Put that stuff in an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you should only define (and test in your code) the symbol, here: `DEMO`

Then, you should conditionally add your symbol to existing symbols (those eventualy defined in project's properties):

In `.csproj` file, after first item `<DefineConstants>` or creating another `<PropertyGroup>` section, add line:

```
<DefineConstants Condition="'$(DEMO)'=='1'">$(DefineConstants);DEMO</DefineConstants>
```

PS: this is a tested solution.