# Can't use System.Diagnostics.Debug

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace test
{
    class Class1
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

It results in the following errors:

> Error CS0103  The name 'Debug' does not exist in the current context  test
>   The parameter to the compiler is invalid, '/define:/d:DEBUG' will be ignored.

[image]

Why can't I use `Debug.Print()`?

Comment: What project did you start with, a .NET Core project?

Comment: What platform are you targeting?

Comment: `Debug` should exist in `System.Diagnostics` for any normal project, regardless of whether the `DEBUG` identifier is defined for the compiler or not. How did you get this project started? What kind of project is this?

Comment: There is no such thing as `Debug.Print`, however, but your screenshot doesn't show you trying to use that so I'm going to guess you're simple misrepresenting the code you're trying to compile in that comment, is that correct?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen There is `Debug.Print()`

Comment: Did you somehow delete the project reference to `System.DLL`?  `System.Diagnostics.Debug` is found in that assembly.

Comment: I suspect that the compiler warning is indicating that the compiler command line is messed up somehow.  See [Define C# preprocessor from MsBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43836548).  That might account for the problem.

Comment: Agh, why didn't I see `Debug.Print` when I checked this, disregard my earlier comment.

Comment: Try changing `Debug.WriteLine` to `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`. When you do that, probably the error message will change. Tell us what the new error message says.

Comment: This is a brand new install of VS 2017. I reinstalled hoping it would fix the problem i was having. I started with a blank c# project but i get the same problem regardless if i start with console app.

Comment: I did try `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hello world");`  it results in the following errors:
`Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Debug' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`